# Using a python package in the current app and its child package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging, python-contextvars

I have a FastAPI app that uses package A as a dependency. On every request to the FastAPI app, package A stores some request string in a [ContextVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#context-variables) inside the package. The FastAPI app also uses package B. This package B uses package A as an internal dependency to get the data of the current context variable and perform some operations with it.

[image]

I tested this scenario, and it works fine. So my question is, how does python manage to share package A resources between the FastAPI app and package B? I mean, how does it work behind the scene?

Note: I use pip as a package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python subdependencies are not isolated, so when your app imports package A, and when package B does, it's the same code (usually `<python location>/site_packages/package_a`). So, if package A creates a global `ContextVar`, which is imported in both your app and package B, it will be the same object.

This is also why you can get package version conflicts; if your app has `package_a==1.0.0` in its `requirements.txt` file, and B has `package_a>=2.0.0`, then the installation will fail, because there is no version that satisfies both those requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand you correctly, no matter how many times a package is mentioned for installation inside the app or its dependencies, it will always be translated to a single package with a single version. Also, the import of its modules anywhere will reference the same object. Also, can you give me a reference that can help me read more about this if you have one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A good place to start would probably be pip's own [documentation about dependency resolution](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/dependency-resolution/).

Comment: One last thing that came to my mind, using `import pkg` vs `import pkg as p` won't make a difference. Python is smart enough to recognize it's the same object. Right?

Comment: You're right, that won't make a difference.